# Rails User Association with comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, comments, associations

I have a User scaffold (DEVISE), a Comments scaffold and a movies scaffold

Currently, Comments are posted on the movie show page.

What i'm having trouble with is having the comment be created by User. So that a comment is create by a User.

So if i display the comment in the `movies/:show`

I could do

Body: `<%= comment.body %>`
Author: `<%= comment.user.first_name %>`

How would I make a comment belong to a user, and only editable and destroy-able BY that user only?

Please dont tell to use `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create,:destroy]`
or follow the Michael Hartl Tutorial with Microposts because I have already done both of these and they dont work

Anyways, does anyone know how I could do this?

MAny Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first I would show the `edit` and `destroy` link only to owner with:

```
<% if comment.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to "edit", ... %>
  <%= link_to "delete", ... %>
<% end %>
```

and then just in case for smart guys who knows how to use inspect element in chrome, I would do a controller level check for comment owner:

```
def edit
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.user == current_user
    @comment.update_attributes(....)
    @message = "Comment updated or created or deleted, depends on method"
  else
    @message = "It's not your comment wise guy :)"
  end
  redirect_to :back, notice: @message
end
```

the same for destroy and update method.

**!not a copy/paste ready code.**

this is what I did once and it worked quite nice, other method you can use `gem cancan` https://github.com/ryanb/cancan and set abilities for users.

```
can :edit, Comment, :user_id => user.id
can :destroy, Comment, :user_id => user.id
```

with setting abilities this way only owner will be able to access edit page and the update, destroy actions.

Comment: And `update`! Otherwise smart user will be able to edit that post.

Comment: yes sure, you are right, for update action you'll have to check o owner too. Thank you for mention this.

Comment: <% if comment.user == current_user %>           This doesnt work because all its doing is saying that the comment is editable if there is a current_user. Furthermore, I had to change the code because with the one you provided, it was hidden to signed_in users where as if i logged out, I could see the actions.

Comment: If i did use can :edit, Comment, :user_id => user.id


Where would that code go?

Comment: can :edit would go into abilities model, it takes time to set it up but in the end works great... about the current_user, how do you save the user_id in comment, aren't you using a current_user or something like this method to have the users saved into session?  http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: As stated in the question, I am using Devise

I just created a comment and when I click to edit that comment i get It's not your comment wise guy :)

Comment: so why would you say that `<% if comment.user == current_user %>` won't work, at this point you just hide the links from others, showing them only to owner, and in the controller you can filter the user again, if current_user does not exists it won't be editable and even accessible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31689/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-user2225129)

Answer (score 1):

what's about devise helper 'current_user'? something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    comment = current_user.comments.where(id: params[:id]).first
    if comment.nil?
      ...
      401 error or something else (current user is not creator of this comment)
    else
     ...
    end
   end
end
```

And also you can check permissions in view:

```
<% if comment.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to "edit comment" ... %>
  <%= link_to "delete comment" ... %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the comment belongs to user, in your `create` action:

```
comment = current_user.comments.new(params[:comment])
```

To make it editable/destroyable only for owner

```
before_filter :find_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authorize_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
#...

private

  def find_comment
    @comment = Comment.find params[:id]
  end

  def authorize_user!
    deny_access if @comment.user != current_user # example
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Making sure that a user is signed in with `:authenticate_user!` is a good thing, but you have to associate the comment with th user too.

`Devise` gives you a `current_user`. So if your `Comment` `belongs_to :user` and your `User` `has_many :comments` write in your `CommentsController`:

```
def new
  @comment= current_user.comments.new
end

def create
  @comment= current_user.comments.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    ...
  end
end

def edit
  @comment= current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @comment= current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
    ...
  end
end
```